# ios - Uilabel & UIimageview in Uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview, uilabel

I want this below type of layout in iPhone (using  UItableview, Uitableviewcell, Uilabel and Uiimageview).

[image]

(assume **light blue dots == uiimageview**)

In each UItableviewcell I have 1 UIimageview and 1 Uilabel.
both control's starting alightment are same TOP LEFT. 
My  uilabel's content are dynamic and image is only one static image.

Image is very small compare to uilabel's content. 
So, my image goes center vertical and horizontally. but I want only on TOP Left corner.

**Edited :**

I have already do this in `Uitableviewcell`

But if Uilabel have number of line is 2 or more then imageview's position is changed.
It goes in center vertically and horizontally. but I want imageview only on top left position whether uilabel's number of line 1,2,3....n

my code is here:

```
    In CommonCustomeCell.m



- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {

self = [super initWithFrame:frame reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];


if (self) {

 dotImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dotPoint.png"]];

        dotImage.opaque = YES;

        [self.contentView addSubview:dotImage];

    titleName3 = [[UILabel alloc] init];

titleName3.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;       

titleName3.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        titleName3.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = FALSE;

        titleName3.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];

        titleName3.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:17.0/255.0 green:72.0/255.0 blue:147.0/255.0 alpha:1];

        titleName3.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;     

        [titleName3 sizeToFit];     

        [self.contentView addSubview:titleName3];

}

-(void)layoutSubviews

{

    frame = CGRectMake(20,2,self.bounds.size.width - 45 , self.bounds.size.height);   

    [titleName3 setFrame:frame];

 frame = CGRectMake(4,10,dotImage.frame.size.width,dotImage.frame.size.height);

    self.dotImage.frame = frame;

}

}
```

In RootViewController.m file

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

    {

     CommonCustomeCell *cell = (CommonCustomeCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

                if (cell == nil) {                

                    cell = [[[CommonCustomeCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    }

     [cell.dotImage5 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myLogo.png"]];

     cell.titleName3.text = [[myArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"];

    }

    }
```

help me, Thanks in advance.

Comment: create custom ’UITableViewCell’, and place imageView anywhere you want.

Comment: can you please show code of creating imageView in your custom cell?

Comment: i have added code here please check that.

Comment: `- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier` is deprecated, you should use `- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier`

Answer (score 3):

- Create `UITableView` with **Section** and grouped style.
- Your `loarem Ipsm` (text) set as a **Section** Title.
- and Create `UITableViewCell` custom cell with `UIImageView` and `UILabel` to display text 
  "loarem Ipsm is simple dummy"

Comment: In this if my Uilabel's number of line is 2 or more,then imageview's position is changed.It goes in center vertically and horizontally. but I want imageview only on top left position whether uilabel's number of line 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 etc...

Answer (score 0):

Have you set autosizing for the CustomCell View same as given in the image below? Only top and left should be enabled.

[image]

Comment: @DhavalSodhaParmar I understood your question. This can happen if customcell view autosizing is set bottom as well as right autosizing enabled. Make sure it should be same as given image. Or you can setFrame of the image view. e.g. [Image setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 167, 37)];

Comment: But I have not used xib file, used only custom class ( Parent Class : UITableviewCell) i have to make universal app for all iOS version.